# [LibGDX]Delay between button presses

Tags: android, menu, libgdx, touch, delay

Im making a very simple game and have started making each menu. There will be 3 menus in a row - Main menu - Playher select Menu - Gamemode Menu but the problem i am facing atm is adding a delay between the touches. the code i have uses Sprites for the buttons and detects whether a touch point is within the bounding rectangle.

Like so:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
    cam.unproject(PlayerMenuTP.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));

     if(Sprites[1].getBoundingRectangle().contains(PlayerMenuTP.x, PlayerMenuTP.y)){

         Game.ChangeScreen(2);

    }
}
```

This works for the first menu but since the buttons are in the exact same position on each menu if you hold you finger on the screen i skips through all the menus.

I don't know how to modify this to wait until the previous touch is no longer occurring then continue to scan for this one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to use Scene2D for UI related stuff, it's not hard to implement or learn, and its very easy to mantain.

Anyway if you want to keep going in that way, you can do this:

1. Make your screens implement InputProcessor.
2. Set Gdx.input.setInputProcessor() to that screen (in the show() create() or the name of the method called when the screen is set)
3. Override touchUp()
4. Replace your code with

   ```
    @Override public boolean touchUp (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
     cam.unproject(PlayerMenuTP.set(screenX, screenY, 0));
     if (Sprites[1].getBoundingRectangle().contains(PlayerMenuTP.x, PlayerMenuTP.y)){
           Game.ChangeScreen(2);
     }
     return true;
   ```

   }